# DVD-RW and 3.5 inch Floppy Drive recognized in BIOS. Neither can be read

Tags: motherboard, bios, dvd, ide, floppy

The bios recognizes both the 3.5 inch Floppy and the DVD-RW, but as I try to boot from the DVD drive, it tries and fails to read any disk.

I installed FreeDOS onto a SATA HDD to test drive function. Both drives spin up and the floppy drive lights up while reading, however the drives both throw an error. I know that the disk drive used to work fine when my dad had the computer however I was forced to replace the motherboard with an identical one because the integrated graphics wouldn't display anything. I know for sure that my cables are set up correctly. I haven't messed around in the BIOS very much except to try and reconfigure the floppy drive.

The motherboard is a [Gigabyte GA-MA785GM-US2H Revision 1.1](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-MA785GM-US2H-rev-10#ov). As per manual specifications all cables are set up correctly. Upon further inspection the DVD drive is jumpered as Master and the floppy drive is hooked up as drive A. As far as I know the floppy drive is separate in the BIOS as drive A.

Comment: *"I don't need to jumper it as a "master"'* -- Incorrect.  Since both IDE and floppy can have multiple drives on one controller port/cable, the proper drive ID/number must be setup/configured.  Some older drivers also required termination resistors.  You only provide summations with vague details, e.g. *"throw an error'*.

Comment: @sawdust My motherboard has two IDE connections, one for a 40 pin IDE drive and one for a 32 pin FDD.I just assumed that since there was only one connector on my IDE cable and only one IDE drive that I didn't have to jumper anything. Do I need to physically jumper it as master period? Also the specific errors they throw in DOS are: a "General Error" for the floppy drive and a "Drive Not Ready" error for the DVD drive.

Comment: There is no interference between FDD and IDE-HDD. But you have to set them to MASTER or SLAVE via the jumpers. I' not sure for the FDD, coz that's a long time ago, but I **am sure** for the IDE-HDDs/PATA-drives. You **have** to set the HDD as master or slave with the jumper (on the drive).

Comment: *"My motherboard has two IDE connections ... and one for a 32 pin FDD"* -- Floppies are not IDE.  How you set drive jumpers depends on the cable you're using.  You also have to install the cables correctly, i.e. not backwards. A clear color photo would help. You're really asking multiple questions, since IDE/ATA can use master/slave/cable-select, and is a completely different interface than floppy (uses a drive number 1/2/3/4).

Comment: @sawdust I did look and the DVD drive is set to "master." I also know that the FDD is wired as drive A. My problem stems from the fact that despite being recognized as such in the BIOS, and despite spinning up and "trying" to read, neither drive is able to send data.

Comment: *"As per manual specifications all cables are set up correctly"* -- Explain what this means.  Does the IDE/ATA cable have 3 connectors?  Describe the connector colors and spacing on the cable.  Which connector is plugged into the mobo?  Which connector is plugged into the DVD drive?  Have you tried jumpering the DVD drive to `CS` instead of `master`?

Comment: @sawdust The IDE cable has 3 connectors, one blue, one black, and one grey in between, with a white wire designating the first pin. The blue connector is plugged into the motherboard, and the black connector is plugged into the DVD drive. The FDD cable also has three connectors, with a twist just before the last connector. The connector opposite the twist is plugged into the motherboard while the connector just after the twist is plugged into the FDD. I'm not sure what the difference is between CS and master, but the jumper is connecting the two pins top/bottom all the way to the left.

Comment: Those connections seem correct.  The DVD drive should have a legend (somewhere) to explain the jumper pinout.  Whatever it is now, suggest you try the alternate to `master` versus  `CS` (cable select).  `CS` would be the preferred selection given your description of the cable.  Test reading using a DVD-ROM (i.e. a stamped disc) rather than DVD+/-RW (chemical dye) disc.

Comment: @sawdust I found the legend, but it doesn't seem to make a difference whether it's in master or CS. I am currently testing with a cd-rom of quake, and a few bootable disks that I know work. I find it unlikely that both of my legacy optical drives don't work, but I don't have another computer with IDE to test the DVD drive. I do however have another  FDD to test just in case, but I'm wondering if it could be related to the motherboard or BIOS. I have another motherboard but the onboard graphics don't work. Would it be worth it to find a cheap graphics card from the XP era?

Comment: Do you have more than one cable to try?  If you're comfortable, try opening the drive, and (carefully) clean out dust.  As to floppy drive, does it perform a recalibrate seek (i.e. full travel of head from outside cylinder to inside back to outside) on boot? (The BIOS may have a selection to inhibit recalibration.)